# Sending mail with java from a brinkster hosted account

Tags: java, email, smtp

I need to send an email from a brinkster hosted account using java. I used this code to send email from my gmail acoount, and it works fine.

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");        
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {

                    return new PasswordAuthentication("gmailuser", "password");

                }
            });

    try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("gmailuser@gmail.com"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse("someone@gmail.com"));

        message.setSubject("subject");
        message.setText("text");

        Transport.send(message);catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

Now, I need the email to be sent from username@company.com.co
I have this

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "mymail.brinkster.com");     //<--changed this
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");        
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {

                    return new PasswordAuthentication("username@company.com.co", "password");      //<--changed this

                }
            });

    try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("username@company.com.co"));     //<--changed this
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse("someone@gmail.com"));

        message.setSubject("subject");
        message.setText("text");

        Transport.send(message);

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

And this doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? I think it may have something to do with the smtp.host but I don't know what.

Answer (score 0):

may i know what type of exception you are getting

every host have different name (mail.smtp.host) make sure that your host name is correct

and in gmail whatever from address u give it won't display as from address

Comment: I get trying to connect to host "mymail.brinkster.com", port 465, isSSL false. then I get connection timed out. I'm not sure what the host name should be, I couldn't find it.

Comment: where could I find the host name? @vikasramireddy

Comment: host name must be provided by the host,don't assume it